# How to solve "cv2. error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow" Error in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

This is the code I am using for capturing video through my webcam:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame= cap.read()
    # frame= cv2.resize(frame, None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Input', frame)
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the error is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.
>    cpp, line 325
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "video_capturing2.py", line 10, in 
>     cv2.imshow('Input', frame)
>   cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:325: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function ims
>   how

How do I solve it? whenever I am running the code above, the `ret` flag is never `True`. I have tried `sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` but still it is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

`imshow` fails when you pass an empty image, as pointed out by @101. In your case, this is most likely due to the fact that you ignore empty frames from `cap.read()` and call `imshow` even if `cap.read` returned an empty image.

To fix this, replace your `while True` loop with a `while cap.isOpened()` or check whether `cap.isOpened()` has been successful before reading frames.