# Open CV Error while running Python Script in colab

Tags: opencv

When I opened the .py file in `colab` using:

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
    print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
    name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

the file loaded and saved properly.
but when I was opening it using the command:

```
python "mypuppy.py"
```

it loaded but an error occurred in Open CV:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mypuppy.py", line 4, in
>   
>       cv2.imshow('puppy.jpg',img) cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion
>   failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

The Original .py file is as follows:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('puppy.jpg')
while True:
    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
    cv2_imshow(img) 
    #If we've waited atleast 1ms AND we've pressed the ESC

    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
       break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "cv2. error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow" Error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739788/how-to-solve-cv2-error-215-size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imsho)

Answer (score 0):

image can't be readed. check if img is not empty first.
you can upload image using this command:

```
!wget "copy paste the image address here"
```